# How to use the CDK library for PdCurses in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, c, project, ncurses

I've successfully installed and used PdCurses in CodeBlocks.
Now, as I am trying to finish the [Ncurses tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), I've read the last part said that there is a utility library which is the CDK that will help make curses apps easier by providing pr-emade dialog console boxes.

I just want to ask on how could I install the CDK library for PDCurses, since it was originally for Ncurses.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDK works fine with PDCurses and MinGW. Since you mentioned CodeBlocks I'm guessing that's what you're using. There are no special steps to compile it in this environment:

1. Download the CDK source package
2. Run MSYS console and do `configure; make' in the source root
3. Copy the resulting libcdk.a file and the header files to somewhere nice that your compiler and/or IDE can find them.
4. Copy the manpages somewhere nice (I personally use the Cygwin man command under Windows).
5. Compile one of the test programs, e.g. buttonbox_ex.c

For reference I used this command to compile one of the examples to verify the library is working:

gcc -Wall -o buttonbox_ex buttonbox_ex.c -lcdk -lpdcurses