# How to implement a scroll or list box in NCurses/PdCurses? ( C )

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I am in the midst of creating a text user interface app for a school project.
I really need help on how to implement a scroll box or list box in NCurses/PDCurses(in C).

As far as I researched, [scrollok](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=scrollok) makes it possible. I have tried it to my project but to no avail.

The scroll box is used for showing list of names vertically and when user presses "N", it scrolls next part and when the user presses "P" it scrolls to previous part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollok` doesn't magically create a scroll box, it just allows the window to be scrolled up. You do not even need `scrollok` for your purpose. Just

- maintain an index *i* to the topmost name which is to be displayed (initially 0)
- **print** height *h* names from index *i* to min(*i+h-1*, *i<sub>max</sub>*) to the window, starting at the topmost line
- when user presses "N", if *i+h* ≤ *i<sub>max</sub>* then set *i* to *i+h*, clear window box, go to **print**
- when user presses "P", if *i* > *0* then set *i* to *i-h*, clear window box, go to **print**

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen CDK ([Curses Development Kit](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/)) it has source code so you can inspect or just use it. There is also [information](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/tools.html) on ncurses site on this toolkit.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer... Yes I have seen CDK, but I'm on windows OS and I'm finding it hard to use CDK on windows (codeblocks)... In fact I have asked it on my last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666090/how-to-use-the-cdk-library-for-pdcurses-in-codeblocks

Comment: @Raven, did you try to compile cdk with `--with-pdcurses`?

Comment: Nope, excuse me for my low on knowledge into this.. But how could I do that? Also, when I tried.. grp.h and pwd.h are not included in windows.